# Volumetric charge density of a Gaussian surface $\rho$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

If I have a long cylinder (infinite length) and has a radius R=4cm , A cross section of it has length $L=15m$ and charge $q=3\mu C$ , The cylinder is surrounded by a thin shell (Thickness$\approx0$) of length $L_2=8m$ has an inner radius $2R$ and charge $2q$ (As shown in the fig.)

Now the problem is if I want to fin the electric field at $r=1.5R$

If I  take a cylinder as my gaussian surface :
$$\oint E.dA=\frac{q_{in}}{\epsilon_0}$$
And since the the gaussian surface is shaped as a cylinder $\therefore$ E is constant and it can be rewritten as
$$E\times2\pi (1.5R)\times8=\frac{\rho \pi (0.5R)^2\times8}{\epsilon_0}$$

Now what is the charge density $\rho$ is it the same as the long cylinder or is it $\frac{q}{Vol.\space of\space gaussian\space surface}$ ?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the geometry.  How can a cylinder of infinite length have a cross section of finite length?  And how can a cylinder of zero thickness have an inner radius?  Note that Gauss' Law can't be applied here; there's not enough symmetry.  I can't be sure about that, however, since I don't understand the geometry

Comment: What is meant by the given length is that we know that on 15m of the cylinder their is a charge q=3$\mu$C from which we can calculate the volumetric charge density $\rho=\frac{\pi (0.04)^2(15)}{3*10^{-6}}$

Comment: The charge density is assumed to be uniform, so it is zero where there is no charge.